# Derivative of a function with different formulas on different intervals

Tags: sympy

Is there a canonical way of declaring a function by parts in *Sympy*? I tried

```
import sympy
import sympy.functions.special.delta_functions as special

sympy.init_printing()
x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
V = x*x * (special.Heaviside(x + 1) - special.Heaviside(x - 1)) \
    + (1 + 2*sympy.log(x)) * special.Heaviside(x - 1) \
    + (1 + 2*sympy.log(-x)) * special.Heaviside(-x - 1)
```

which defines a differentiable function, but

```
print(V.diff(x).simplify())
# Prints: (x*(x**2*(-DiracDelta(x - 1) + DiracDelta(x + 1)) - 2*x*(Heaviside(x - 1) - Heaviside(x + 1)) - (2*log(-x) + 1)*DiracDelta(x + 1) + (2*log(x) + 1)*DiracDelta(x - 1)) + 2*Heaviside(-x - 1) + 2*Heaviside(x - 1))/x
```

Is there a way to somehow tell *Sympy* to simplify  `DiracDelta(x - a)*f(x)` to `DiracDelta(x - a)*f(a)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piecewise-defined functions are implemented by [Piecewise](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) class. Your function would be expressed as

```
V = sympy.Piecewise((1 + 2*sympy.log(-x), x < -1),
                    (x**2, x < 1),
                    (1 + 2*sympy.log(x), True))
print(V.diff(x))
```

which prints `Piecewise((2/x, x < -1), (2*x, x < 1), (2/x, True))`

The `(expr, cond)` pairs in `Piecewise` are processed in the order given: the first `cond` that evaluates to True (if the preceding evaluated to False) causes the corresponding `expr` to be returned.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! And `sympy.ccode()` works with that, while it didn't with `Heaviside()`. :)